# Вопрос о курсоре (mac os но возможно и web и windows)

Tags: javascript, windows, веб-программирование, telegram, mac

Проблема в том что есть сайт на котором спрятан курсор в принципе ( cursor: none )
но когда на мой mac приходит уведомление с другого приложения например (telegram) курсор снова становиться видимым пока мы не нажмем на страницу. Кто нибудь знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: По всей видимости у вас просто окно браузера теряет фокус, и появляется курсор. curcor: none работает в пределах рабочей области страницы, но не системы. Вы тут ничего не сделаете

Comment: Самое интересное в этом то что в браузере курсор продолжает двигаться в месте с новым(

Comment: это как? Сразу 2 курсора у вас появляется? В другом браузере тестировали? Обработали ситуацию, когда страница теряет фокус? А когда снова получила фокус? Проблема только на macos или других системах тоже?

Comment: страница не видит событий blure and focus, так что подозреваю что за появление еще одного курсора ответственен не браузерю